# Unable to disconnect Heroku app from GitHub Account

Tags: heroku, github, continuous-integration

We're using Heroku Pipeline and GitHub integration:

1. Staging app was manually deployed with `git push heroku master`.
2. Production app was automatically deployed upon commit to Master on GitHub repo.

I want to change this workflow so that:

1. Staging app is automatically deployed upon commit to Master on GitHub repo.
2. Production app is the result of a Staging app being promoted.

Thus, I need to unlink the Production App from the GitHub Account/Repo. The instructions are here:

[GitHub Integration | Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#disconnecting-from-github)

But, in my case, there's no "Disconnect" button:

[image: This is the whole width of the screen]

How can I disconnect it?

Comment: Try to go to Github personal settings -> Authorized applications -> revoke access on Heroku. It should disconnect automatically

Comment: @Mr.Phil that would affect other apps that are integrated (and meant to be that way :) )

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought about that. Might be useful for someone who has just one app though so I'll leave the comment

Comment: We also didn't see a "Disconnect" button, so I just disconnected the account and the re-authorized Github. Sadly, this automatically connected the repositories again, so that trick didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to `Manage Account`: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/applications

- Click `Applications` tab

  - In `Third-party Services`: these are 2 options:

    - `Re-authorize` or `Revoke access`

      - click `Revoke access`

*Remember to `clear cookie` or `use incognito mode` to re-login by another Github account*

Answer (score 3):

You can also revoke access of heroku dashboard from your github account.

1. Login Github
2. Go To Settings
3. Applications
4. revoke the connected heroku dashborad that will automatically disconnect your heroku from your github account.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Github and under your personal settings revoke access BUT THEN go back to Heroku, logout, login and you will see a warning from Heroku on the dashboard saying that access has been revoked from your GitHub account.

Click on Disconnect on that app.

Then reauthorize the others.

Comment: I had to logout and log back in in order for Heroku to recognize that my github repo was no longer present (was transferring to another organization).

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Heroku's Dashboard.

Whenever the app was part of a Pipeline, it was impossible to disconnect it from the original github deploy hook.

Now the "disconnect" button is also available within pipelined apps.

Comment: I've operate permission and as of 11.08.2018 I don't see a disconnect button on my pipelined app.

Comment: If it's a new organization you are part of, you have to "reauthorize" GitHub - and select "Grant" on that new org. when the authorization page pops up.